# GridGain Off Heap doesn't work

Tags: bigdata, gridgain

could, please, someone take a quick look, what is wrong with my code, that is supposed to store cache in Off Heap Memory through GridGain?

My configuration is quite the same, as on the wiki page (http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Off-Heap+Memory)

My configuration is following:

```
<!-- Enable OffHeap -->
<property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="#{2L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L}"/>

<!-- Always store cache entries in off-heap memory, evict to Swap. -->
<property name="memoryMode" value="OFFHEAP_TIERED"/>
```

However, jconsole shows, that data is still written to the heap memory, as it is fluctuating and when I try to get data, that I've stored, I get the zero result.

Code is following:

```
final GridCache<String, Object> cache = grid.cache("partitioned");
for (long i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    cache.putx(String.valueOf(i), hundredBytes.clone());

    if (i % 1024 * 1024 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i + "bytes inserted");
    }
}

System.out.println("Cache size: " + cache.size());
```

The last one line shows me "Cache size: 0". That's strange, probably, I do not quite understand, how to access Off Heap memory. Is there other/separate API for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, there is another one API

```
GridCache<String, Object> cache = grid.cache("partitioned");
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> localIterator = cache.offHeapIterator();
```

However, pay attention, that 'grid.cache("partitioned")' in case of storing data on heap returns the cache for whole cluster, but 'cache.offHeapIterator()' in case of storing data off heap returns only data for the local node in a cluster.

This confused me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points about the on-heap/off-heap difference:

- There is no difference between on-heap and off-heap data storage when you access your data by key: `grid.cache("partitioned")` still works with the cache of the whole cluster, not just local entries. You can access your data by key using `cache.get(...)` methods regardless of the node you execute your code on.
- There are different methods which returns local size of on-heap and off-heap memory. `cache.size()` returns number of on-heap entries stored in cache. `cache.offHeapEntriesCount()` returns number of entries stored in off-heap storage. `cache.swapKeys()` returns number of entries stored in swap.
- Entry iterators for on-heap, off-heap and swap always return local entries for the node. If you need a whole cache iteration, you can use scan query or broadcast a closure which will iterate over local entries.

Comment: Thanks, Alexey, for your answer, however, I see another one situation on gridgain 6.2.1. cache.offHeapEntriesCount() tells me, that there is the data in collection and I can access that data using offHeapIterator. However, trying to access data using 'int[] partitions = cache.affinity().primaryPartitions(grid.localNode());' doesn't returns the data. But when I disable Off Heap, the recent code works